# Permuation, disjoint cycles proof by induction.

Tags: abstract-algebra, induction, permutations

I am having a hard time writing out a general proof. Can anyone please help?
Thank you.

Exercise:

Show that any k-cycle (a1,......,ak) can be written as a product of some number of (k-1) 2-cycles. Conclude that any permutation can be written as a product of some number of 2-cycles. Do a proof by induction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that cycles are composed from right to left.

As the exercise tells us, we proceed by induction on $k \in \mathbb N$.

**Base Case:** For $k = 1$, we note that $1$-cycles are (by convention) not written, and so any $1$-cycle can be written as a product of $(1 - 1 = 0)$ $2$-cycles.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that our claim holds true for $k' = k - 1$, where $k \geq 2$.

It remains to prove that our claim holds for $k' = k$. To this end, consider the $k$-cycle:
$$
\alpha = (a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_{k-1},a_k)
$$
Indeed, observe that we can rewrite $\alpha$ as:
$$
\alpha = (a_1,a_k)\underbrace{(a_1, a_2,\ldots, a_{k-1})}_\beta
$$
Now observe that $\beta$ is a $(k-1)$-cycle. By the induction hypothesis, we can write $\beta$ as a product of $(k-2)$ $2$-cycles. By left multiplying this product with the $2$-cycle $(a_1,a_k)$, we have expressed $\alpha$ as a product of $((k-2)+1=k-1)$ $2$-cycles, as desired. $\blacksquare$